# What additional settings are required to use an SSL certificate on a non-default website in IIS 8?

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate

I installed an ssl certificate on a website but https doesn't work.
I have a server with O.S. Windows server 2012 R2, IIS 8 connected to internet via fixed IP. In IIS, in addition to the default website (Default Web Site), I have added other websites that I can manage by setting the 'host name' field in the binding property with the relative address of the various sites (wwww.miosito.it).
I recently bought an SSL certificate from aruba to use on just one non-default site.
After importing the certificate into IIS with the 'Complete certificate request' procedure (I used the .p7b file which contains both the certificate and the CA) and binding to my site, I can't reach my site with the address https://miosito.it from any browser and it tells me 'The site cannot be reached, connection denied by www.miosito.it'. I wonder if it's a problem with importing and configuring the SSL certificate or the fact that I manage multiple sites and therefore need further settings?
The certificate also seems to have been imported correctly because when I go to bind it via the binding property, I choose it directly from the drop-down list and then leave port 443.
Can you tell me how to proceed?

How can I reach my website with https?

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html Run a report and the cause should be clear.

Comment: Based on your description only, it's hard to determine the cause of the problem because there are so many possibilities. You can check that your SSL certificate is valid and correctly issued by a trusted CA with an online SSL certificate verification tool. Also, make sure your firewall allows port 443.

Comment: Ok solved. Thanks for the port 443 suggestion. I hadn't set port 443 on the router. Now works

Comment: Hi, I turned my comment into an answer, if this was helpful, you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can check that your SSL certificate is valid and correctly issued by a trusted CA with an online SSL certificate verification tool. Also, check your firewall and router configuration, make sure your firewall and router allow incoming HTTPS connections on port 443 to reach your server.